# Unity3d 3d skybox not quite right

Tags: unity-game-engine, skybox

I'm messing around in unity3d in order to learn it.
Had a crack at making my own 3d skybox like in source engine for example. I'm using the standard 1st person controller.
I made another camera with same FOV for my skybox, and slaved it to the camera in the 1st person controller using the script below which I put on my skybox camera.
(Maincam field has the 1st person controller camera component in it)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraSlave : MonoBehaviour {

    public Component Maincam;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    transform.rotation = Maincam.transform.rotation;
    }
}
```

You can see result [here.](http://bam.net16.net/skyboxtest/) Its a bit funny. (The big tetrahedron shape in the background is in my skybox everything else is normal)
As far as I understand it as long as the camera fov is the same it doesnt matter what size my skybox things are.
I think the problem, is there is some lag maybe? Like the Update in the code above is being called one frame too late? I tried calling that update from the 1st person controllers mouse look script but as well as getting loads of errors the result was the same.

Comment: Please update your link, it's broken. (8:03a, Oct 2, 2013)

Comment: Weird its working for me. This is link  http://bam.net16.net/skyboxtest/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't visualize your example, btw:

> I think the problem, is there is some lag maybe? Like the Update in
>   the code above is being called one frame too late? I tried calling
>   that update from the 1st person controllers mouse look script but as
>   well as getting loads of errors the result was the same.

You can't rely on the order in which `Update` method will be called by the engine (unless you force a particular order, but this isn't generally a good choice). For camera update operations it's better to use [LateUpdate](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.LateUpdate.html). It's guaranteed that it will be called after all `Update` methods.

Comment: Yes. Thats what I needed. It totally fixed it. thahks! :)